# add existing anaconda to jupyter notebook mac

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've installed anaconda2 and anaconda3 from official website
and now have 2 folders:
user/anaconda with anaconda2
user/anaconda3/anaconda with anacaonda3
the default path for python is set for anaconda 2:

```
 MacBook-Air:anaconda zelenov$ which python
/Users/zelenov/anaconda/bin/python
```

but when I run jupyter notebook I can create only python 3 notebook

how can I add my python2 environment?
I tried this, but it didn't help:

```
 python2 -m pip install ipykernel
    python2 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one Anaconda distribution, not both.  I suggest uninstalling one of those distributions, e.g. Python 2.  Then [create an environment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment) within your Python 3 distribution:

```
> conda create --name py27 python=2.7
```

Once the environment is created, you need to enter it, install `ipykernel`, then exit the environment once completed.

```
> source activate py27
> conda install ipykernel
> source deactivate
```

**Note `source` can be omitted for Windows users.**  As of Anaconda 4.2, installing `ipykernel` is sufficient for creating a jupyter kernel automatically.  Start jupyter:

```
> jupyter notebook
```

You should see a dropdown menu in the dashboard with the name of the py27 kernel installed.  For more information on installing Python kernels, see [Jupyter documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html).